# BLOWFISH: Restore key from plainttext and hash?

Tags: cryptography, blowfish

Is it possible to restore the key from blowfish encrypted ciphertext and plaintext pairs?

I have several strings both encrypted and plain. But I can't remember key.

example of encrypted string `24026B7101030657757D01`
decrypted string is `AC C1312463`

```
$key = '';
$plaintext = '';
$crypttext = '24026B7101030657757D01';

$cache = array();

while($plaintext != 'AC C1312463')
{
  $key = random_string();
  while(array_search($key,$cache) !== FALSE)
  {
    $key = random_string();
  }
  $cache[] = $key;

  $bf = new Crypt_Blowfish($key);

  $plaintext = $bf->decrypt($crypttext);
 }
    print_r($key);
    die();
```

Let's say I have algorithm like this. How should function random_string should look like to get 32bit random key?

Comment: Blowfish is a blockcipher, not a hash. There is BCrypt, a blowfish based password hash, but it doesn't have a key. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: Only by guessing the input. Just like restoring the key is only possible by guessing it. For sufficiently complex keys it's infeasible. But unless you clarify your question, we can't help you, since Blowfish is no hash, and your question thus contains a contradiction.

Comment: my mistake, hash is not the right word, i should say crypted string instead, i fixed question

Answer (score 5):

No decent cipher (including Blowfish) allows efficient key recovery no matter how many (plaintext, ciphertext) pairs you know.

What remains is a brute-force attack where you guess the key and then check if it matches a known pair. For sufficiently complex keys this becomes prohibitively expensive. So this will only work if your key was bad.

Comment: is there a standart length of key or its just limited by max number of characters?

Comment: @PetrVelký Blowfish supports keys from 32 to 448 bits. 32 is easy to bruteforce, 64 bits becomes annoying, 80 bits might be possible for powerful attackers like the NSA, and at around 100 bits nobody on earth will be able to break it.

Comment: how would you setup string generator for breaking 32 bit key? lets say in PHP or any other programming language BTW thanks for your interest and help

Comment: I added my code for brute force, how would you setup function for generating random 32 bit key ?

Comment: you don't want to generate random 32-bit keys, you want to test all 32-bit keys.  so you want a counter instead of a random generator

Answer (score 1):

What you are proposing is esentially a [known-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known_plaintext_attack), that said, as the wiki article points out, they haven't been a successful key recovery mechanism since the days of the Enigma.

To even get close to a modern key recovery system, you need to use a *chosen* plaintext attack like [Differential cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_cryptanalysis), which analyzes differences in ciphertext between specially chosen plaintext pairs to gain info about the key.  That said, Blowfish isn't particularly susceptible to such attacks, so it won't help much anyways.

If you want to recover your key, you should consider the mechanisms that were used to generate it (is it derived from a password, how big is it, etc) and then come up with a way to brute force it, whether through a dictionary attack, iterating through all 32 bit integers, etc.  a program called John the Ripper may help with applying this brute forcing as efficiently as possible.

Comment: Matsui's linear cryptanalysis works against DES, used only known plaintexts, and DES is much newer than Enigma.